# What are the suttas in which the Buddha describes suffering as "burning"

Tags: reference-request, sutras

I remember reading suttas in which the Buddha describes suffering, lust or other unwholesome mind states as burning. What are these suttas?

Answer (score 4):

You may be thinking of the [Fire Sermon (SN 35.28)](https://suttacentral.net/en/sn35.28).

It says that the senses and so on are aflame ... aflame with lust, hatred, and delusion.

In more detail, it says the following are aflame:

- Sense-organ, sense object, sense-consciousness, and sense-contact
- Any feeling[s] arising from the senses ... including suffering (*dukkha*), but also *sukha*

... and aflame with:

- The three poisons
- Also birth, ageing, and death
- And sorrow and so on